# How to generate unevenly spaced numbers based on input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, distribution

I'm calculating the Empirical CDF as follows:

```
>> import numpy as np
>>> from statsmodels import api
>>> sorted_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,100,150]
>>> const_npoints = 10
>>> xvals = np.linspace(sorted_list[0], sorted_list[-1], const_npoints)
>>> ecdf = api.distributions.ECDF(sorted_list)
>>> yvals = ecdf(xvals)
>>> print xvals
[   1.           17.55555556   34.11111111   50.66666667   67.22222222
   83.77777778  100.33333333  116.88888889  133.44444444  150.        ]
>>> print yvals
[ 0.09090909  0.81818182  0.81818182  0.81818182  0.81818182  0.81818182
  0.90909091  0.90909091  0.90909091  1.        ]
```

From above you can see that `yvals` is missing valuable information that occurs at the beginning of my `sorted_list`. This is because of my `linspace` function that creates equally spaced values. Is there a way I can generate `xvals` to represent the distribution of `sorted_list`?

Comment: Have you tried concatenating several `xvals` pieces, each generated with different ranges and concentrations?

Comment: What's the purpose of the desired xvals? There are many ways to pick some values. The easiest would be `xvals = np.unique(sorted_list)` which gives you all step points of the ecdf.

Comment: @user333700 The purpose of `xvals` is to get a number of constant points. Let's say, my `sorted_list` has 100 values, I still only want 10 points for my `xvals` that sort of represents the distribution of values found in `sorted_list`

Comment: @hpaulj Can you be more specific? For a given list, how will you select the range?

Comment: something like `xvals = np.unique(sorted_list[:: len(sorted_list) // 10])` which might end up with less than 10 and often doesn't include the largest value.